# Calendar String.valueOf()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar

Im currently trying to make a calendar app but somethings wrong in my code and I cant dint it. Currently ive made a calendarView and set an onSelectedDateChangeListner and im assigning string with year, month and day. I pass this values to another class with an intent, but it stands this date(2015.04.20) even thoug I click another date. Sorry for my english, it isnt my mother tongue. Heres the relevant code:

MainActivity.java:

```
    mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new                   CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int   month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String calYear = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            String calMonth = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
            String calDay = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            Intent newEvent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalendarEvent.class);

            newEvent.putExtra("YEAR", calYear);
            newEvent.putExtra("MONTH", calMonth);
            newEvent.putExtra("DAY", calDay);

            startActivity(newEvent);
        }
    });
```

CalendarEvent.java

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        mYear = extras.getString("YEAR");
        mMonth = extras.getString("MONTH");
        mDay = extras.getString("DAY");
    }

    TextView hello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helloworld);
    hello.setText(mYear + "/" + mMonth + "/" + mDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the values of Calendar c instead of the values of the changed date.  You can set the calendar instance that you are using by calling "c.set()"

```
mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new                   CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int   month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        String calYear = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String calMonth = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
        String calDay = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        Intent newEvent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalendarEvent.class);

        newEvent.putExtra("YEAR", calYear);
        newEvent.putExtra("MONTH", calMonth);
        newEvent.putExtra("DAY", calDay);

        startActivity(newEvent);
    }
});
```

though, I think all you are trying to do is this:

```
mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new                   CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int   month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Intent newEvent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalendarEvent.class);
        newEvent.putExtra("YEAR", String.valueOf(year));
        newEvent.putExtra("MONTH", String.valueOf(month));
        newEvent.putExtra("DAY", String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));
        startActivity(newEvent);
    }
});
```

Comment: When i used the code down it got written null, null, null. But i figured it out, just did this:
                String mYear = year + "";
                String mMonth = month + 1 + "";
                String mDay = dayOfMonth + "";

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to convert to string.  I'll amend.